# Trigger scroll event for '1 px' in another function

Tags: jquery, scroll, triggers

Is there any way to trigger scroll event by `px` eg: for `1px`

I have tried:

```
$('html,body').trigger('scroll');
```

and:

```
$(window).trigger('scroll');
```

but it's not working as I have expected. Is there any other way?
I want to trigger this in another `click` function.

Comment: It would be simpler to extract the logic that's executed when the `scroll` event fires to it's own function which you can just call directly without having to fake an event, or scroll the window by N pixels to force the event

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan There in many events and logic and action inside it and many of them are not created by me, so I can't extract them to other function that's why this work around bro.

Comment: Why **negative vote** on the question please do explain your vote so I can rectify my self.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
window.scrollTo(window.scrollX, window.scrollY + 1);
```

Comment: it's not working properly, it's not triggering the scroll.!

Comment: Yeah ofc it does. That was what you were asking? "Is there any way to trigger scroll event by px eg: for 1px"

Comment: in the above comment I meant *not* instead for *now*, but Sorry for that bro now it's working properly I just increased the `1` to`5` and its working now.